# Dynamic import image in Vue-3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vuejs3

I'm trying to show a dynamically imported image, but it's not working with the error

> 'Cannot find module'

This is my component

```
<template>
      <div class="footer">
        <div v-for="footerItem in getters" :key="footerItem.id">
          <img :src="methods.requireImage(footerItem.icon)" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from '@/store'
import { requireImage } from '@/modules/images'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Footer',
  setup () {
    const store = useStore()
    const methods = {
      requireImage
    }

    return {
      getters: store.getters.getFooterItems,
      methods
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

And this is module

```
export const requireImage = async (link: string) => {
  // return require(link)
  const image = await import(link)
  return image
  // const images = require.context('../assets', false)
  // return images('color-circle.svg')
}
```

Commented out code not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass the full path to `require` in a variable, Webpack can't load the image.  This is roughly because it's a build-time tool, and the path is created at runtime.  If you hard-code at least some of the path though, that will be sufficient:

```js
export const requireImage = link => {
  return require(`@/assets/${link}`);
}
```

<sup>Note: *Removed the unnecessary `async` or the return value would be a promise*</sup>

Your variable `footerItem.icon` should just contain the filename `color-circle.svg` now that some of the path is hard-coded in the call to `require`.  With that done, you can use the method in the template as you wanted:

```html
<img :src="methods.requireImage(footerItem.icon)" alt="">
```

Be aware that at the moment your wrapper method is unnecessary because you could get the same result from:

```html
<img :src="require(`@/assets/${footerItem.icon}`)">
```

Comment: Thanks! After a zillion tries I made it work... I'm not sure why lint is not throwing an error when I import the function but it does when I try to use require directly...