# Vue: load image from asset folder in Typescript code

Tags: typescript, image, vue.js, canvas, assets

i have an issue trying to load images form the assets folder to the canvas.

the path to the images are: /src/assets/1.jpg /src/assets/2.jpg /src/assets/3.jpg

my code:

```js
<template>
  <canvas id="CanvasTest" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'CanvasTest',  
    data() {
      return { images_src: ["/assets/1.jpg","/assets/2.jpg","/assets/3.jpg"] }
    },
    mounted() {
      const canvas = document.getElementById('CanvasTest') as HTMLCanvasElement;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;

      const img_w = 200;
      const img_h = 100;

      for (let i = 0; i < this.images_src.length; i++) {
        const imgElement = new Image();
        imgElement.src = this.images_src[i];
        imgElement.onload = () => {
          ctx.drawImage(imgElement, i*img_w, i*img_h, img_w, img_h);
        };
      }
    },
  });
</script>

<style>
  #CanvasTest {
    background-color: #555;
  }
</style>
```

i get these error:

GEThttp://localhost:8080/assets/1.jpg
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]

GEThttp://localhost:8080/assets/2.jpg
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]

GEThttp://localhost:8080/assets/3.jpg
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]

[image of the browser console with the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9UM7.png)

i found a solution which is to upload/move the images to the **public folder**, but i don't really like that. I would like to know if there are better ways to upload the images from the **assets folder**.

Comment: please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: errors in text form are above the image link

Comment: try the answer shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66092645/6225326) and turn your image links into require statements